Artifact when creating and filling in a 2d list in Python
Predefining a "matrix":
m = [[0] * 2] * 3 

Changing one element at position 0,1:
m[0][1] = 1

Checking:
print(m)    
[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]

All the elements m[0], m[1] and m[2] have now 1 at position 1. Why?
They seem to be a reference to the same object. Why? And how to work it around.

"Why? They seem to be a reference to the same object" yes, that's precisely what is occuring. You create a list with the innner expression with [0] * 2 (this is evaluated precisely once), resulting in a list with 2 references to the same int object (which is fine, since int objects are immutable so their identity is irrelevant). Then,  the exact same thing happens with the outer expression, [list_you_created] * 3 Python the language (and the standard library) will almost never implicitly copy an object. Of course, a third party library could do so

the standard workaround would be somethign like [[0 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)], or even [[0]*2 for _ in range(3)]

Another way to think of this is, number = 0; sublist = [number, number, number]; m = [sublist, sublist, sublist]

or, even another way, [[0, 0, 0]]*3 is equivalent to temp = [[0,0,0]]; temp + temp + temp
